# Interpolation and single quoted strings in SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby

I just started of with databases with SQLite3 and Ruby. I have run into a problem with my ruby code here.

I want to create a code where the user adds another record to the database. Now here is my problem.

User sawa found the solution of my first problem. Thank you!

NEW PROBLEM*

```
puts "Enter name for the new user"
x = gets.chomp
puts "Enter the type of the user"
y = gets.chomp

$db.execute('insert into customers(id,name,type) values (11,"#{x}","#{y}")')
```

When I run this code and input the x any y value it will return in my database #{x} and #{y} and not the values I created.

Comment: Now you put the double quotes in the wrong place. Don't put them right around `#{}`. Put them around the whole string.

Comment: $db.execute("insert into customers(id,name,type) values (11,#{x},#{y})") When I do this and run my code I get another problem. It says that there is no such column for my input. But isn't it a record I'm creating? I'm not creating a column here..

Comment: In order to create a record, the columns for the record have to exist in the table in the database.

Comment: Be aware that your `execute` allows for [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: That's the wired part becuase they do exists. my id,name and type columns are there. There is already existing data in there. my id is an INTEGER, the other two ones are VARCHARS. I also found it wired becuase when I make just a random string instead of having the #{x} and #{y} values it will create data into my database

Comment: I found the solution of the problem. I have to use the single qoute around the #{x} and #{y} to make it work. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3):

You're actually going about this all wrong. You shouldn't be using string interpolation for SQL at all, you should be using placeholders and bound variables. The [README even includes an example](http://rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/file/README.rdoc#SYNOPSIS):

```
# Execute a few inserts
{
  "one" => 1,
  "two" => 2,
}.each do |pair|
  db.execute "insert into numbers values ( ?, ? )", pair
end
```

and the [fine manual](http://rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3/Database%3aexecute) even mentions bound variables in the second sentence:

> **`- (Object) execute(sql, bind_vars = [], *args, &block)`**
>
> Executes the given SQL statement. If additional parameters are given, they are treated as bind variables, and are bound to the placeholders in the query.

So you should be saying this:

```
$db.execute('insert into customers (id, name, type) values (?, ?, ?)', 11, x, y)
```

or this:

```
$db.execute('insert into customers (id, name, type) values (?, ?, ?)', [11, x, y])
```

Answer (score 2):

As is warned, don't use single quotes. Use double quotes. Expressions in single quotes are not ignored. They are evaluated literally.